# Replacing all .equals(string) with == (int)

Tags: java, inequality

My java project uses objects that have an `ArrayList` of Strings. These strings are, however, predetermined. There are only 47 or so possible Strings. Now I want to check if an `ArrayList` contains a certain `String`.

I currently do this through `.equals()` , but I believe that's quite slow, so I want to switch to `==` (int). It is, however, quite annoying to manually turn all `.equals()` into `==` (int). Especially when things have to be changed again.

So is there a tool that turns all these `.equals()` to `==` (int) for a set of Strings?

Comment: why not use some form of a hashing set?

Comment: I could be understanding the question wrong but if you want to check if an arraylist has a certain string, can't you just use the contains method that are provided for lists in java?

Comment: Hi Stew, I think your thinking of the editor replace all functionality.  However, I don't think it is a good idea to do what you are planning.  There is a reason the .equals method is different that the identity '='.  There are plenty of ways to test if an array contains a value.  See https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-check-if-array-contains-a-certain-value/ for some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of premature optimisation (it's the root of all evil). There are plenty of resources describing this in detail. In short, it's important to measure the performance impact of any optimisation you make and weigh it against code readability. In this case, I would imagine you are reducing readability for negligible affect on performance.

It's also worth noting that accurate measuring performance is an entire subject on its own. It's difficult to get meaningful results if the differences are small because there are about a million factors other than the actual code which can affect performance - especially Java, with it's hotspot compiler.

Without seeing code, it's hard to appreciate your exact application. However, you may be able to improve performance without decreasing (or potentially improving?) readability by using enums in an EnumSet. Again, if improving performance is your primary goal, it's important to measure to see if your changes actually improve anything.

You may be also be able to simplify your existing String#equals code using [List#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

If they are all predetermined can you just use an enum? Enums are basically a list of named numbers with some extra helper functions.

```
public enum myStrings
{
    firstString,
    secondString,
    lastString
}
```